# How to create a search form in rails that invites Users to Projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, project

I have Project show page wich shows all details of a project.

I wish to **create a search form** on that page, **that would search through all Users** (based on either their user name, first name or last name) **and upon selection invite them to the project**.

When they accept the invitation, their profile picture would be added next to the project name in project show page.

How to code the form and the invitation mechanism most elegantly?

Comment: There are lots of guides on how to create a search form. I know the RailsCasts have one. After that, set up links (from the search result) that go the server to set up the invitation (however you want to do that) and go from there. Then if there's a more specific thing you're stuck on, you can ask.

Comment: thanks. I saw RailsCasts tutorial but it is very out of date (08). But I'll check it out anyway. Do you know any other good tutorials for search forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [thinking sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/quickstart.html) gem to use in your project. This is a efficient engine for search.